# reading contents from webpage in python

Tags: html, python-2.6

I've a requirement where I need to extract the contents from the webpage as shown the the Image, I need to get the list with all the contents shown under Parent Directory. i.e the list should contain "FileServices-1.2.0.16-20150507.191658.iso","FileServices-1.2.0.24-20150702.223315.iso  " etc. But the costraint is I do not have to parse the HTML page and the contents are NOT always .iso sometimes it contains pdf's or txt file etc.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Why is parsing the HTML not an option? Or do you mean not parsing it yourself as in "a lib parsing it for me is ok"? You could extract all visible text from the html by a parser lib like beautiful soup and search for patterns ending in .iso.

Comment: Thanks for your time.
the ultimate thing the python script should do is, for a given url it should list the files as shown in image. HTML should not be parsed because the contents will be of different format like pdf, txt etc.
If at all I parse HTML is there a generic way to parse any type of the files??
Any pseudocode will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are mixing the actual HTML with linked files. What you have is a HTML document with many <a> elements which you want to extract. In the web you have files that are linked to each other through plain text URLs. That said your file list could contain any imaginable file linked - this doesn't change the way you read the links.